# How to parse XElement values to a model object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read the XML element and pass it from a controller to a partial view. With the code below, I am getting System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) returned null.

Model:

```
public class DowJonesIndustrialsModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Ticker")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Exchange")]
    public string Exchange { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Industry")]
    public string Industry { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date Added")]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddStocks()
    {
        XElement xEle = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\amitd\Desktop\MVC\MVCPlayground.com\MVCPlayground\Areas\DowIndustrial\xmlData\DowJonesStocks.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> stocks = xEle.Elements();
        List<DowJonesIndustrialsModel> dowStocks = new List<DowJonesIndustrialsModel>();
        foreach (var stock in stocks)
        {
            dowStocks.Add(new DowJonesIndustrialsModel
            {
                Name = (string)stock.Element("Name").Value,
                Symbol = (string)stock.Element("Symbol").Value,
                Exchange = (string)stock.Element("Exchange").Value,
                Industry = (string)stock.Element("Industry").Value,
                DateAdded = Convert.ToDateTime(stock.Element("DateAdded").Value),
                Id = int.Parse(stock.Element("Company").Attribute("Id").Value)

            });
        }
        return PartialView("_StockListings", dowStocks);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@using MVCPlayground.Areas.DowIndustrial.Data 
@model List<DowJonesIndustrialsModel>

<div>
    @if (Model == null)
    {
        <p>no items found</p>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Ticker</th>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Exchange</th>
                        <th>Industry</th>
                        <th>Date Added</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Id</td>
                        <td>@item.Symbol</td>
                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                        <td>@item.Exchange</td>
                        <td>@item.Industry</td>
                        <td>@item.DateAdded</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    }
</div>
```

View:

```
@using MVCPlayground.Areas.DowIndustrial.Data
```

@model DowJonesIndustrialsModel

```html
@using MVCPlayground.Areas.DowIndustrial.Data
@model DowJonesIndustrialsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>XML in Action</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ClearResults() {
        $("#displayResultDiv").empty();
    }

</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddStocks", "DowThirty", new { area = "DowIndustrial" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "displayResultDiv" }, new { id = "DowStocksChartForm" }))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Symbol, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Symbol, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Exchange, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exchange, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Industry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Industry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DateAdded, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateAdded, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Company" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <br />
                </div>
            }
            <div id="displayResultDiv"></div>
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderAction("AddStocks", "DowThirty");}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DowJones xmlns="DowJonesIndustrialAverageStocks">
  <!-- Dow Stocks -->
  <Company xmlns="" Id="1">
    <Symbol>MMM</Symbol>
    <Name>3M</Name>
    <Exchange>NYSE</Exchange>
    <Industry>Conglomerate</Industry>
    <DateAdded>08/09/1976</DateAdded>
  </Company>
  <Company Id="2" xmlns="">
    <Symbol>AXP</Symbol>
    <Name>American Express</Name>
    <Exchange>NYSE</Exchange>
    <Industry>Financial Services</Industry>
    <DateAdded>1982-08-30T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Company>
  <Company Id="3" xmlns="">
    <Symbol>AAPL</Symbol>
    <Name>Apple, Inc.</Name>
    <Exchange>NASDAQ</Exchange>
    <Industry>Information Technology</Industry>
    <DateAdded>2015-03-19T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Company>
  <Company Id="4" xmlns="">
    <Symbol>BA</Symbol>
    <Name>Boeing</Name>
    <Exchange>NYSE</Exchange>
    <Industry>Aerospace</Industry>
    <DateAdded>1987-03-12T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Company>
  <Company Id="5" xmlns="">
    <Symbol>CAT</Symbol>
    <Name>Caterpillar, Inc.</Name>
    <Exchange>NYSE</Exchange>
    <Industry>Construction</Industry>
    <DateAdded>1991-05-06T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Company>
  <Company Id="6" xmlns="">
    <Symbol>CVX</Symbol>
    <Name>Chevron</Name>
    <Exchange>NYSE</Exchange>
    <Industry>Petroleum</Industry>
    <DateAdded>2008-02-19T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Company>
  <Company Id="7" xmlns="">
    <Symbol>MTB</Symbol>
    <Name>M and T Bank</Name>
    <Exchange>NYSE</Exchange>
    <Industry>Finance</Industry>
    <DateAdded>2002-12-02T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Company>
</DowJones>
```

Comment: `int.Parse(stock.Element("Company").Attribute("Id").Value)` should be `int.Parse(stock.Attribute("Id").Value)`

Comment: oh my goodness! Thank you pfk. I don't know why I am learning programming.... :)

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse(stock.Element("Company").Attribute("Id").Value) should be int.Parse(stock.Attribute("Id").Value).

Thanks pfk